# How to delete fields with bigger than a value in mysql

Tags: mysql

can somone please correct the folowoing mysql statement

```
DELETE * FROM `wx_comments` WHERE `f_code` > 18014
```

I want to delete everything from a table where f_code is bigger than 18014

Thanks.

Comment: IF you leave out the asterisk `*`, the back-tick quotes `\``, and quote the value in the `WHERE` clause that should work, I think: `DELETE FROM wx_comments WHERE f_code > "18014";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just drop the `*`:

```
DELETE FROM `wx_comments` WHERE `f_code` > 18014
```

See the [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) syntax reference.

Answer (score 3):

You don't [need the * in a delete (docs link)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

```
DELETE FROM `wx_comments` WHERE `f_code` > 18014
```

Is f_code a number or string?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the backtick quotes `\`` necessary/optional? It's been a while since I've used MySQL, so my IIRCs aren't as C as they could be... =/

Comment: @David Thomas: Exact rules are here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html Basically, anything "odd" requires quoting, In this, not needed though, so I guess preference/standards